# Iterating through a dataframe then adding data from another dataframe depending on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes A & B, I am adding a column in dataframe A and trying to fill it up depending on the values of three columns in dataframe B.

This is dataframe B:

```
    Clinton    Trump       State
0   151581.0   130614.0    Alabama
1   68429.0    91087.0     California
2   62435.0    89199.0     Arizona
3   22927.0    72846.0     Alaska
4   58669.0    33928.0     Arkansas
```

This is dataframe A:

```
    State       Education             Percentage
0   Alabama     NOHighSchoolPercent   0.85
1   Alabama     PostgraduatePercent   0.55
2   Alabama     BachelorsPercent      0.69
3   Arkansas    NOHighSchoolPercent   0.80
4   California  NOHighSchoolPercent   0.72
```

I want to add a column "Majority" in A that either says "Trump" or " Clinton" based on the number of votes in dataframe B. The first condition is that the states should match, and the second condition checks who got more votes.

The resulting dataframe A should look something like this:

```
        State       Education             Percentage   Majority
    0   Alabama     NOHighSchoolPercent   0.85         Clinton
    1   Alabama     PostgraduatePercent   0.55         Clinton
    2   Alabama     BachelorsPercent      0.69         Clinton
    3   Arkansas    NOHighSchoolPercent   0.80         Clinton
    4   California  NOHighSchoolPercent   0.72         Trump
```

I know how to add a column and assign a condition, the trouble is that the conditions are between 3 columns in a separate dataframe (B)

I was thinking something along those lines:

```
def get_result(votes_clinton, votes_trump):
    if votes_clinton > votes_trump
        return 'clinton'
    else
        return 'trump'

A['Majority'] = B['Clinton','Trump'].map(get_result)
```

However I still need to account to whether the states are equal and this is where the code structure gets confusing

Note: Some states may not be present in both dataframes

Comment: Ok, and what was the attempt? What went wrong?

Comment: I have tried researching for an answer and couldn't find a workaround for applying 2 or more conditions at the same time. That is besides applying said conditions to a separate dataframe

Comment: Applying multiple conditions to a filter is fundamental to pandas/numpy. Joining the data is trickier, but there is no end of resources for the former

Comment: I edited my question, I added what I have thought of so far.

Comment: `df['match'] = np.where(df['Trump'] > df['Clinton'], 'Trump', 'Clinton')`. It's a single condition check, I'm not sure exactly how it should be joined with the other df. `Education` is irrelevant?

Comment: Is DataFrame B one row per state?

Comment: Dataframe B has one state per row yes. Dataframe A has almost the same states as B but the same state could be mentioned more than once in A.

Comment: @roganjosh Dataframe A's columns are relevant, its just that I am adding a new column "Majority" to A, then putting "Clinton" or "Trump" for every row depending on the voting numbers for every state

Comment: As an aside why do you not want `NOHighSchoolPercent`, `PostgraduatePercent`, `BachelorsPercent` to be a column? It seems like it complicates the current dataframe B.

Comment: @akozi You mean have them as separate columns? Well they were, I used .melt to put them in one column because I am doing a data visualization project with a new language that prefers the data to look that way

Comment: @HassanDbouk ah that makes sense. And yea I meant to type seperate columns. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join is on a single non-duplicated column in `dfb`, so `map` is appropriate. Set the index then use `.idxmax(axis=1)`.

```
dfa['Majority'] = dfa.State.map(dfb.set_index('State').idxmax(1))

print(dfa)
#        State            Education  Percentage Majority
#0     Alabama  NOHighSchoolPercent        0.85  Clinton
#1     Alabama  PostgraduatePercent        0.55  Clinton
#2     Alabama     BachelorsPercent        0.69  Clinton
#3    Arkansas  NOHighSchoolPercent        0.80  Clinton
#4  California  NOHighSchoolPercent        0.72    Trump
```

---

The restult of `dfb.set_index('State').idxmax(1)` is a Series, indexed by `'State'`, which can be used to map the `'State'` in `dfa` to the majority candidate.

```
State
Alabama       Clinton
California      Trump
Arizona         Trump
Alaska          Trump
Arkansas      Clinton
dtype: object
```

Comment: Does this method account for Dataframe A having the same State name more than once? I'll edit my question above for clarity

Comment: I edited the question, states in dataframe A are mentioned more than once, example "Alabama"

Comment: @HassanDbouk yes. The important thing is that in `DataFrame B` the state is not duplicated. Each unique state in `dfa` gets mapped to the same majority candidate based on the above Series.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked! I kind of wish python was a little bit more like Java/C# in a sense that I can loop through dataframe A, then inside the loop, loop again through dataframe B, check the state names, then check the votes, then assign "Clinton" or "Trump", its more computing but is straightforward

Comment: That is certainly possible. But it winds up being both more verbose and less performant so typically not suggested. While it's probably not an issue with these small `DataFrames` it's common for people to be working with millions of rows, in which case you just cant loop.